# Is there a schema versioning tool for cassandra

Tags: cassandra

In the sql world, it's quite common to have a tool that goes through a folder of schema scripts to set up some schema. A widely used approach is to have a table holding the current db version number, and ddl scripts so that we can start from any version of the db and update to any subsequent version in a controller manner. Visual Studio has db projects, redgate have similar tools.

I was wondering if there's something for cassandra as well. I know it won't be too difficult to implement something basic for cassandra, but was wondering if somebody's already done it.

Comment: Good question. I didn't find anything, so ended up building my own not too long ago.

Comment: Awesome...github link? :)

Comment: Not currently. I'd need to break out the couple classes into a separate project. You're not the first person to ask (here's part of the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867756/create-cassandra-database-with-jenkins/24872280#24872280) so I'll have a look to see if it can be easily done.

Comment: The solution I'm talking about is Java. What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using C#....I was thinking of doing something around scripts around cqlsh, bash / powershell / possibly python.

Comment: I'll have to pass on doing a non-Java version right now. Too much other stuff going on. Still gonna play with a Java version, though.

Comment: I broke everything out into a separate component and added it to github (see my answer below). It's Java, not c#, but perhaps can provide an example to work from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initial question doesn't specify a language, though you later indicate you'd like C#. I don't have a C# answer, but I've extracted the Java versioning component that I'm using for my project. I also created a small sample project that shows how to integrate it. It's bare-bones. There are different approaches to this problem, so I picked one that was simple to build and does what I need. Here are the two GitHub projects:

https://github.com/DonBranson/cql_schema_versioning

https://github.com/DonBranson/cql_schema_versioning_example

This component doesn't store a version # in the schema, but stores the list of scripts it's run. It depends on the sort order of the script names to determine run order. Very basic.

Answer (score 8):

Pillar manages migrations for your Cassandra data stores.

Pillar grew from a desire to automatically manage Cassandra schema as code. Managing schema as code enables automated build and deployment, a foundational practice for an organization striving to achieve Continuous Delivery.

Pillar is to Cassandra what Rails ActiveRecord migrations or Play Evolutions are to relational databases with one key difference: Pillar is completely independent from any application development framework.

https://github.com/comeara/pillar

Comment: Any 2022 alternative? The project seems abandoned

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is by its nature is 'schemaless'  it is a a structured key-value store, so it is very different from a traditional rdbms in that regard.

Cassandra has now evolved to be 'schema-optional'  in that it allows to you describe general datatypes that live in a particular column family.

Try looking at Liquibase and/or Flyaway to see if the extensions provide the versioning capability you require.

http://bungeedata.blogspot.com/2013/12/liquibase-and-cassandra.html

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1

http://planetcassandra.org/blog/schema-vs-schema-less/

Comment: Yes...I'm aware of how schema differs in cassandra to an rdbms. Still, using CQL3, we are defining column families (tables), and indexes etc. using DDL. As such, a tool for maintaining versions would seem useful

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a schema migration tool that could be used for the following scenarios:

Automated upgrade to schema when an application is deployed.
Allow test Cassandra databases to be populated for integration tests.
After some searching, I've found the following two that look like potential candidates:

https://github.com/Contrast-Security-OSS/cassandra-migration
https://github.com/DonBranson/cql_schema_versioning

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that exists today.

To the extent that you're using **CQL** you could probably come up with something but you'll likely run into problems with the limited abilities of **CQL** to modify tables and then with transformation phase.

When I've used these types of tools with SQL, I always ended up with a bunch of SQL to update the data set after the application of updated DDL.

With **CQL**, I've had to write code to be applied after the schema change.

If all you're doing is adding or dropping tables, columns and indexes, it should be do-able.